# NHibernate OrderByDescending throwing exception `A recognition error occurred`

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

When using:

```
.OrderByDescending(review => review.Country.Id == reviewCountryID)
```

the SQL query is generated correctly and no error is thrown.

When using:

```
.OrderByDescending(review =>
    review.User != null &&
    review.User.Country != null &&
    review.User.Country.Id == userCountryID
)
```

an exception is being thrown:

```
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException
A recognition error occurred.

at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ErrorCounter.ThrowQueryException()
at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlTranslator.Translate()
at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.DoCompile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow, String collectionRole)
at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, ref IQuery query, ref NhLinqExpression nhQuery)
at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Any suggestions of how to fix this issue or an alternative?

Thank you!

**Update**

Updated the OrderBy to actually include the null checks.

Projecting in the `Select()` the expression `review.User != null && review.User.Country != null && review.User.Country.Id == 144` works as intended, but the same conditions in the OrderBy throw the exception.

**Update**

Following fixes the issue for multiple joins **but not when doing boolean conditions on them which is what the question asks for**:

Do the OrderByDescending using the projected property and then project back only the entities queries on, for example:

```
.Select(review => new
{
    Review = review,
    ReviewUserCountryId = (review.User != null && review.User.Country != null) ? review.User.Country.Id : (int?)null
})
.OrderByDescending(review => ReviewUserCountryId)
.Select(reviewInfo => reviewInfo.Review) // for aliasing assuming that ReviewUserCountryId won't be needed later in the query
// rest of query
```

Comment: what are you putting a boolean condition in orderBy, shouldnt boolean condition go in where clause and the orderBy should be just on a property you want to order?? Order by should be just `.OrderByDescending(review => review.Country.Id)` move other checks to where clause

Comment: @entre: I do not need to filter by the condition, I just need to order by the condition being true descending.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that for multiple joins NHibernate refuses to order on booleans.

A solution is to sort on projection to integers in the OrderBy, for example:

```
.OrderByDescending(review => (review.User != null && review.User.Country != null && review.User.Country.Id == userCountryID) ? 42 : -42);
```

If there is a better solution please add it.

Comment: Using `42` is always the preferred approach.